# Spring Authorization Server not working after Boot 3.2 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

After upgrading to Boot 3.2.0, my Spring Authorization Server is not working anymore, showing a `No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` error when trying to authenticate using the Authorization Code flow:

[image]

I am using the minimal configuration as shown on the Spring Authorization Server ["Getting Started" docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 3):

This change in the behavior is explained in the Boot 3.2 Release notes:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#auto-configured-user-details-service

> The auto-configured `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` now backs off when [...] `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` [...] is on the classpath. [...]
>
> If you are using one of the above dependencies yet still require an `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` [...], define the required bean in your application.

The `spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server` has the Spring Security Resource Server library as one of its dependencies, making the form login fail because of this.

So, I have now created an issue in the Spring Boot project to point this out and confirm this is expected behavior, or otherwise, if they are going to contemplate changing the behavior for the Spring AS minimal setup:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38864

This issue was also reported on the Spring Authorization Server project:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1475

Finally, a temporary solution until this is defined is to declare an `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` bean as suggested in the Release Notes.

For example, if we want to replicate the Boot autoconfiguration using `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password` application properties we defined, we can declare the following bean:

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(SecurityProperties properties) {
    SecurityProperties.User user = properties.getUser();
    List<String> roles = user.getRoles();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(User.withUsername(user.getName())
        .password(user.getPassword())
        .roles(StringUtils.toStringArray(roles))
        .build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Gerardo said it is a bug. per the links he posted. adding this bean fixed for me:

```
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }
```